# Получить значение ячейки Excel и вывести на экран

Tags: php, html, phpexcel, xls

Нашел в интернете примеры кода. Пытался совместить, чтобы получать значение ячейки и выводить на экран. Но что-то пошло не так... Кто может помочь решить эту проблему? Заранее благодарен

```php
<?php
require_once 'PHPExel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$pExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('test.xlsx');

foreach ($pExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $tables[] = $worksheet->toArray();
}
$pExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$aSheet = $pExcel->getActiveSheet();
$test = $pExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellValue('B2')
echo "| $test |";
?>
```

Comment: >Но что-то пошло не так.., сообщение об ошибке вы нам не покажете из принципа?

Comment: @strangeqargo >Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/ermprod/public_html/table.php on line 15

Comment: вы точку  с запятой в предпоследней строке забыли поставить в конце.

Comment: @strangeqargo, пошли ошибки с библиотекой. Хотя в пути к ней, я уверен. Warning: require_once(PHPExel/Classes/PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ermprod/public_html/table.php on line 2
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPExel/Classes/PHPExcel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ermprod/public_html/table.php on line 2

Comment: ты уверен, а php  лучше знает. скорее всего ты запускаешь файл из каталога, в котором нет этих файлов. Кстати, закрывающие теги ?> - дурной тон, убери их.

Comment: @strangeqargo, может вы знаете как решить данную проблему? Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getCellValue() in /home/ermprod/public_html/table.php on line 14